# Unable to fetch the entire data from kafka topic to cassandra using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, cassandra

I want the data from MySQL to Cassandra in real time using Apache Kafka.
Here is my producer code in python

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import pymysql.cursors

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                                     user='root',
                                     port=3306,
                                     password='Mysql@123',
                                     db='bank_transaction',
                                     charset='utf8mb4',
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "Select * from transactions"
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
data = ""

for row in rows:

    
    
    producer.send('demo', json.dumps(row).encode("utf-8"))

cursor.close()
connection.close()

# configure multiple retries
producer = KafkaProducer(retries=5)
```

This is the sample output I'm getting after running a simple kafka consumer

> {u'status': u'INITIATED', u'stped': u'STP', u'remark': u'adkaDKA',
> u'cr_cust_id': 4321, u'txn_Id': u'FT123456', u'currency': u'USD',
> u'dr_cust_type': u'Retail', u'dr_cust_id': 1234, u'bank_user': u'FO
> MAKER', u'txn_start_date_time': u'3/1/2022 8:00', u'txn_code':
> u'FT001', u'dept': u'FRONT OFFICE', u'txn_end_date_time': u'3/1/2022
> 8:30', u'source': u'Mobile', u'amount': 1000, u'dr_cust_acct':
> 1234567890, u'txn_Type': u'Fund Transfer', u'dr_cust_name': u'Vimal',
> u'cr_cust_name': u'Vivek', u'cr_cust_type': u'Retail',
> u'cr_cust_acct': 987654321} {u'status': u'INITIATED', u'stped':
> u'STP', u'remark': u'adkaDKA', u'cr_cust_id': 4321, u'txn_Id':
> u'FT123456', u'currency': u'USD', u'dr_cust_type': u'Retail',
> u'dr_cust_id': 1234, u'bank_user': u'FO CHECKER',
> u'txn_start_date_time': u'3/1/2022 8:00', u'txn_code': u'FT001',
> u'dept': u'FRONT OFFICE', u'txn_end_date_time': u'3/1/2022 8:30',
> u'source': u'Mobile', u'amount': 1000, u'dr_cust_acct': 1234567890,
> u'txn_Type': u'Fund Transfer', u'dr_cust_name': u'Vimal',
> u'cr_cust_name': u'Vivek', u'cr_cust_type': u'Retail',
> u'cr_cust_acct': 987654321}

Here is the consumer code to store the data from kafka topic to cassandra

```
from encodings import utf_8
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy

def interpret_constant(c):
    try:
        if str(int(c)) == c: return int(c)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        if str(float(c)) == c: return float(c)
    except ValueError:
        return c

cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('test')




print("After connecting to kafka")

consumer = KafkaConsumer('demo',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

def insert(message):
    msg = message.value.decode('utf-8')
    #print(msg)
    msg = json.loads(msg)
    print(msg)

    keys = ",".join(msg.keys())
    values = ','.join(str(v) for v in msg.values())
    user_insert_stmt = session.prepare("insert into response ({0}) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)".format(keys))
    #msg = json.loads(message.message.value.decode('utf-8'))
    #msg = message.message.value.split("|")
    #print(msg)
    new_msg = [interpret_constant(x) for x in msg.values()]
    #print(new_msg)
    return session.execute(user_insert_stmt,new_msg)

for message in consumer:
    insert (message)
```

After running the above code, I'm only getting 9 rows of data in cassandra (it should be 49). And the int data type values not showing in cassandra

```
select * from response;



txn_id    | amount | bank_user  | cr_cust_acct | cr_cust_id | cr_cust_name | cr_cust_type | currency | dept         | dr_cust_acct | dr_cust_id | dr_cust_name | dr_cust_type | remark  | source        | status    | stped | txn_code | txn_end_date_time | txn_start_date_time | txn_type
-----------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+---------+---------------+-----------+-------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------
  AC123456 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |       Retail |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |      HNI-VIP | adkaDKA |        Mobile | COMPLETED |   STP |          |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |    ACCT TO ACCT
  TT123456 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |       Retail |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |          SME | adkaDKA |            IB | COMPLETED |   STP |   TT0001 |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |  CHEQUE DEPOSIT
  FT123456 |   null |        SYS |         null |       null |        Vivek |       Retail |      USD |       SYSTEM |         null |       null |        Vimal |       Retail | adkaDKA | BRANCH MANUAL | COMPLETED |  NSTP |          |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |   Fund Transfer
 FT1234567 |   null |   FO MAKER |         null |       null |        Kunal |       Retail |      USD | FRONT OFFICE |         null |       null |        Manan |       Retail | adkaDKA |        Mobile | INITIATED |   STP |   TT0001 |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |   Fund Transfer
  FTM12345 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |         CORP |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |         CORP | adkaDKA |        Mobile | COMPLETED |   STP |          |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |    DIRECT DEBIT
  FD123456 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |       Retail |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |         CORP | adkaDKA | BRANCH MANUAL | COMPLETED |   STP |   FD0001 |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |   FIXED DEPOSIT
  MC123456 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |      HNI-VIP |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |      HNI-VIP | adkaDKA |            IB | COMPLETED |   STP |          |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 | MANAGERS CHEQUE
  RR123456 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |       Retail |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |       Retail | adkaDKA |            IB | COMPLETED |   STP |          |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 | CHARGE REVERSAL
 CHG123456 |   null | BO CHECKER |         null |       null |        Vivek |          SME |      USD |  BACK OFFICE |         null |       null |        Vimal |          SME | adkaDKA | BRANCH MANUAL | COMPLETED |   STP |          |     3/1/2022 8:30 |       3/1/2022 8:00 |  CHARGE POSTING
```

Cassandra table description

```
CREATE TABLE test.response (
    txn_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    amount int,
    bank_user text,
    cr_cust_acct int,
    cr_cust_id int,
    cr_cust_name text,
    cr_cust_type text,
    currency text,
    dept text,
    dr_cust_acct int,
    dr_cust_id int,
    dr_cust_name text,
    dr_cust_type text,
    remark text,
    source text,
    status text,
    stped text,
    txn_code text,
    txn_end_date_time text,
    txn_start_date_time text,
    txn_type text
) WITH additional_write_policy = '99p'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND cdc = false
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND extensions = {}
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99p';
```

Python version 2.7, Kafka version 2.7.0, Cassandra version4 4.0.1.
What changes to make if I want the entire data from kafka topic to Cassandra?

Comment: By the way, I'd suggest using Debezium for taking data from MySQL to Kafka, and Datastax Kafka Connector for writing it from Kafka to Cassandra. That should require very little actual code.

Comment: Otherwise, 1) Please use Python3... 2) try adding `producer.flush()` after your SQL row loop and adding `auto_offset_reset='earliest'` into the consumer constructor